# Escape ampersands in Netcat

Tags: netcat

How can I send the following command to ncat.exe from the Windows command line?

The following command works fine.

```
echo GET /main/main.js HTTP/1.1BHost: www.example.comBConnection: closeBB | tr "B" "\n" | ncat -C www.example.com 80
```

The following request doesn't work because of the ampersands, I think.

```
echo GET /main/main.js?param1=true^&param2=true HTTP/1.1BHost: www.example.comBConnection: closeBB | tr "B" "\n" | ncat -C www.example.com 80
```

If there any workaround to escape the ampersands? I've been trying something like this, but to no avail.

```
set "req=GET /main/main.js?param1=true^&param2 HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.example.com\nConnection: close\n\n"
echo %req% | tr "B" "\n" | ncat -C www.example.com 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes around the string you want to `echo`, i.e.:

```
echo "GET /main/main.js?param1=true^&param2=true HTTP/1.1BHost: www.example.comBConnection: closeBB" | tr "B" "\n" | ncat -C www.example.com 80
```

but as an improvement on the `tr` thingy, it would be better to use something like:

```
echo -e "GET /main/main.js?param1=true^&param2=true HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" | ncat -C www.example.com 80
```

that is assuming the echo command on Windows supports the "-e" flag.